# LoadTestException Error in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, load-testing

The configurations are:

**Test Mix Model**: Based on the user pace. 5 Unit Tests, Each 30 per user per hour

**Network Mix**: 100% LAN

**Load Pattern**: Constant Load Pattern. 25 Users.

**Run Settings**: Running only on my machine. One Agent.

***Results***:

Name      Avg. Test Time (sec)

Test1        38.1

Test2        32.1

Test3        30.3

Test4        26.5

Test5        13.3

Failed Tests: None.

**Errors**:

The Average Test Time of 31.763 seconds for Scenario 'LoadTesting' is too large for tests to be executed at the rate of 150 tests per user per hour specified by the test mix.

Are there any thresholds for average test time ?

Comment: The information provided is incomplete and inconsistent. The exception is because multiplying the average test time by 150 will take longer than one hour. However the inconsistency is that you say the configuration is 30 per hour. Please provide full configuration details plus average test times; show them as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: @AdrianHHH. Added the configurations in detail. Also how does the load testing work. How are the average test time calculated.

Comment: @AdrianHHH. Also How many times a unit test is run is variable in my case. How is it variable?

Comment: Same question now asked on Microsoft forums. I think they are a better place for this question that appears to be asking for basic tutorial information on how to do load testing. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d0bb57ab-5081-4cf7-bb2c-f5c439497a7d/how-to-analyse-load-test-results-that-are-running-on-some-unit-tests-?forum=vstest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test configuration wants each virtual user to perform 150 transactions per hour. The average test time is just over 31 seconds. Thus 150 tests will take 31*150 seconds = 4650 seconds which is about 1h 17m 30s. So the required number of tests do not fit into the specified hour. Hence the exception. (Using the average of 31.763 seconds, gives 1h 19m 25s.)

I suggest rerunning the test and specify half, or even less, the transactions per hour, ie reduce to 75 or lower. Observe how the test runs at that rate and then work up to a test that more closely matches the rate required. It may be that the current performance test is successful and has determined that the system being tested does not work quickly enough.

Comment: So here we can say that the my tests are running inadequately, if I have to attain this rate of transactions?

Comment: @DarshnikSwamy I do not understand your comment.

Comment: @DarshnikSwamy Of course the unit tests take time to execute. You said in the question that they take an average of 31.763 seconds each.